# The cheapest and quickest way to get from Cuba to India

Tags: air-travel, budget, india, cuba

What is the best route to get to Cuba from India?

In airways. Cheap and quick. And has a balance between those two.

Comment: bearing in mind, 'safe' is relative. Locals would consider it 'safer' than foreigners, and more naive people consider almost anywhere safer than cautious people.  We aim to ask questions on here that can be answered *objectively*.

Comment: In addition, you've asked 3 questions in one, it's definitely better to split them up and ask them separately.  Some may know the answer to one, and not the other.

Comment: For now I'm closing this question, as currently it doesn't match the terms in the [FAQ].  However you can edit it to just one objective question and flag it, and we'll definitely reopen it if it's suitable then.  I look forward to seeing it - Cuba is on my list for the near future, so always interested in reading about it.

Comment: Hi @BROY.  Thanks for editing. However, the remaining question is still subjective, not objective.  What is 'best'? Is it the fastest? The most fun? The cheapest?  Each person has a different version of what 'best' is in this case.  You need to explain what 'best' means for you in this case, and then we can try to help.

Answer (score 5):

For the quickest, you either want a direct flight, or a change at an airport on the [great circle path](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=BLR-HAV&DU=mi).

I can't seem to find an Indian airlines serving Havana directly, so that's the first option out. For the 2nd option, the great circle path goes over Scandinavia. So, for that, your best bet would be to change there.

Unfortunately, according to the [wikipedia list of airlines serving Havana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Mart%C3%AD_International_Airport#Airlines_and_destinations), I don't think that any of the Scandinavian airlines go there.

Next best would be the UK - it's not far off the great circle path. Virgin Atlantic fly to Havana from London Gatwick, and they also fly to a number of airports in India. Assuming the connection times in London work from your home airport, that'll be the quickest. Not sure if it's the cheapest though (I searched for some random dates about 2 months into the future, and the price was around the INR40,000 mark for a return, which seems a little high). There are a number of UK based charter airlines that serve Cuba, who are often quite cheap, especially if you book accommodation with them. It may be worth checking if a return to the UK on any of the airlines that serve the UK from India, followed by changing airlines onto a charter flight to Cuba will be cheaper, as I suspect it will be. Disadvantage of this is you'll need to exit airside to re-check your bags, and that will probably need a different kind of visa...

In addition to going via the UK, Air France serve quite a few Indian cities, and fly to Cuba from Paris, and aren't that much further off the great circle. Some thing for KLM from Amsterdam.

Comment: Charter flights from Toronto or Montreal in Canada for example are quite cheap, +-250$ one-way, and there are many flights from those cities to India.

Comment: India to Cuba via Canada add quite a lot of time to the journey though, so would no longer count as "quickest"!

Comment: @yms BLR-HAV is 9606 miles, BLR-LHR-HAV is 9661 miles, BLR-BJS-HAV is 10920. Going via Bejing rather than London is therefore a fair way off the great circle path. Not sure why you therefore think it counts as a good alternative given how much longer it is?

Answer (score 3):

india to Cuba, Best route ans cheapest will be from Delhi to Moscow and then Moscow to Havana by Aeroflot Airline.